# Suitable form for adding/removing elements of a dynamic list

Tags: website-design, usability, web-app, lists

I am writing a web app for tracking daily activities. The concept is very simple, you add questions and then answer them daily. 
When you are defining your questions, you can add different types of question, one of them being multiple choice (where you can have more than one answer).

In the following example, the user is defining a question where the valid answers are (*morning, evening, night*). The feature I am implementing will let users define goals for the question.

I am trying to avoid having a complex form, but the followin is the only way I could come up that would enable the user to configure different goals for the question. Since there are multiple valid answers (the user can anser [`morning,evening`] or just [`evening`], it seems that I will have to manage a dynamic list for the goals.

Is this the best choice?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flkFR9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Uploaded the image sample for visual illustration on the concept. So it means that all your Goals and Preferential setting go together.If you want to add more questions make an additional row of buttons on the header section.

Answer (score 0):

Am looking at it from a very conceptual level, where could this be done in a more graphical manner. Say, your GOALS were prefixed - the GOAL list will be the main screen. Ex. Workouts in morning/evening are shown and stacked as an icon (say a time clock), so as this app opens up - can the daily activities be mapped to the section of workouts? So if I did workout only in the morning, I will select the "Morning Time clock", where the counts will add on to the particular time clock. All these counts can be clicked to find details of when this action "workout" been carried. Somehow the date should be backward integrated through database.

There are subtle intuitive patterns that needs to be adopted as you go along.  All your actions can move in a swipe pattern or carousel and proceed sequentially.

To look at the current option and there could be a "Flag or icon" showing the goal next to the task directly. Goals achieved/ under-achieved can be differentiated with a color, to change the goals mid-way - this icon can be clicked and viewed in a window where once again a graphical representation should be good enough. A clock that can be swivelled around with a counter box next to the clock. Its completely controlled with more graphic manner, since doing it in traditional way on a app might be monotonous.

I had looked at your objectives from a differing perspective, such as if you could largely turn the work from outside-in, doing lots of graphical punch to it.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot or post a link to an example? Your idea sounds nice, but I cannot fully visualize it. Thanks